# meteor issue TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

Having an issue with my meteor project.  I haven't worked on it in awhile and after updating and running I got this.

```
    => Exited with code: 8
W20140306-15:04:49.602(-8)? (STDERR) 
W20140306-15:04:49.603(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/goddard/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140306-15:04:49.604(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140306-15:04:49.604(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140306-15:04:49.607(-8)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
W20140306-15:04:49.608(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/collections/settings.js:3:36
W20140306-15:04:49.608(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/collections/settings.js:26:3
W20140306-15:04:49.608(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/goddard/Projects/meteortest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140306-15:04:49.608(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140306-15:04:49.609(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/goddard/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140306-15:04:49.609(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/goddard/Projects/meteortest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

I am also using meteorite to run this project.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your code to me.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the contents of `settings.js`, but I'll make a guess: You are calling `remove` on a collection which isn't defined at the moment the `remove` is called. Options include: moving your collection definitions under `/lib` or calling the `remove` inside of a [startup](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup) function.

Comment: Have you checked connections to how you've specified dependencies in package.json? It could be that a module you depend on has had a breaking interface change in a recent version. If your package.json's version spec for the module is such that it allows an update to this (hypothetical) more recent version, but your code (or that of another module you depend on) is assuming on the old interface, you could easily run into this scenario. I see this from time to time.

Comment: to provide a complete answer, we really need to see this line in your code: `app/server/collections/settings.js:3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not worked on it on a while there are a few updates you need to do:

- Files are now variable scoped so if you have defined a collection, say `var Mycollection` in one file, it will not be accessible by another, hence why you may get lots of `undefined` errors.

If that helped you, you have a longer list of updates to also do:

- Packages have been namespaced too, so in addition to being variable scoped, files are namespaced. (Note this may also cause your problem). You need to export variables with `api.export` in your packages.

These are the updates that may have caused a problem for you, you haven't given enough details to see which one, but you can see a list of update notes/what has changed in the notes when you updated it or at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md